# Recently started using socket.io - what security measures should I take before releasing the site to the public?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, security, socket.io

The socket server doesn't handle any logins or any inputs from the user, it just delivers information TO the user from a mysql database when it becomes available. Having not worked with socket.io before I don't know what things I should look out for when developing with it. For example can someone access the contents of the .js "server"? Because mine contains some sensitive data like sql credentials.

Comment: Check out: https://www.christian-schneider.net/CrossSiteWebSocketHijacking.html. Also make sure that you're authenticating all requests made through your socket server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.io` has pretty much the same security issues as any web server and web requests.  Providing you haven't done anything silly to expose your server side files, they would not generally be accessible.  We'd have to see your actual server-side code to know if you've accidentally exposed anything there.  The main thing to protect your server and your SQL database is that you have to validate all incoming parameters to make sure nothing you aren't expecting is sent to you that could cause your code to accidentally do something that is not intended.

And, one big thing to make sure you're avoiding with SQL queries it to make sure that nothing that is sent to you is directly put into a SQL query as this exposes you to SQL injection attacks where an attacker sends you parameters you aren't expecting which you put into a SQL query which ends up allowing them to run their own SQL on your SQL server.  There is much [written about SQL Injection in other articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection+attack) if you want to learn more about it.

Since you say that you don't handle any logins, you presumably know that you could get any arbitrary number of socket.io connections and pretty much anyone could be connecting (whether from a browser or from some other custom written agent).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No, I'm not handling logins or anything, it's pretty much one-way only (server-client). And I know about sql injection, xss, rfi and pretty much every common vulnerability you can have in a regular website, just that it's my first time using sockets and I wasn't sure if there's anything particular I should prepare for.